# Grab a screenshot of an obscured window

Tags: objective-c, macos, quartz-graphics

I'm using CGWindowListCreateImage to obtain a screenshot. I'm trying to grab a specific window, whose windowID I know. This is the code I'm using, but it always seems to grab the entire screen, including all windows.

```
CGImageRef windowImage = CGWindowListCreateImage(
      CGRectNull, 
      kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, 
      windowID, 
      kCGWindowImageBoundsIgnoreFraming);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You're asking it to grab the entire screen, including all windows, so you're getting exactly what you asked for. Look at [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/reference/CGWindow_Reference/Reference/Functions.html):

> *windowOption*
>
> > The options describing which windows to include in the
> >     image. Typical options let you choose all windows or windows above or
> >     below the window specified in the windowID parameter. For more
> >     information, see “Window List Option Constants.”

For this value, you're passing `kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly`, which means:

> List all windows that are currently onscreen. Windows are returned in order from front to back. When retrieving a list with this option, the relativeToWindow parameter should be set to kCGNullWindowID.

Technically, it's not even legal to pass this option with a windowID, but if you do, Quartz is nice and just ignores your ID.

If you want your screenshot bounded to the window's screen rectangle, you need to pass that, not `CGRectNull`. And if you want your obscured window rather than what's in front of it, use `kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenBelowWindow | kCGWindowListOptionIncludingWindow` for your options.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. The `kCGWindowImageBoundsIgnoreFraming` option is documented to allow specifying a `CGRectNull`:

> When the requested capture rectangle is `CGRectNull`, using this option captures the window area only and does not capture the area occupied by any window framing effects.

But for me I then had to specify `kCGWindowListOptionIncludingWindow` as the only window option. This contradicts a little what the documentation says:

> You must combine this option with the `kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenAboveWindow` or `kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenBelowWindow` option to retrieve meaningful results.

But if I followed that advice, the screenshot was always the whole screen. So to sum it up, the following worked for me as expected:

```
CGImageRef windowImage = CGWindowListCreateImage(
      CGRectNull, 
      kCGWindowListOptionIncludingWindow, 
      windowID, 
      kCGWindowImageBoundsIgnoreFraming);
```

(Or almost as expected - the screenshot still contained the titlebar of the window and I had hope that `kCGWindowImageBoundsIgnoreFraming` would mmean that the titlebar of the window is skipped as well).